# I get "Session 'app': Error" when trying to debugg in android studio

Tags: android, debugging

I can debug the first time I try to debug. But when I try to do it again it fails me and gives me the "Session 'app': Error"-message.

I tried to kill the app through the terminal, and then debug but got the same answer anyway.

Does anybody know why I get this message. And does anybody have a solution for me?

regards

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:-

Go to **build -> rebuild project -> run**

That's it.